# How to use summarize and group_by?

Tags: r, dplyr

Data camp: Prompt: Use the functions filter, group_by, summarize, and the pipe %>% to compute the average and standard deviation of systolic blood pressure for females for each age group separately.
Within summarize, save the average and standard deviation of systolic blood pressure (BPSysAve) as average and standard_deviation.

My code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(NHANES)
data(NHANES)
```

Task: complete the line with `group_by` and `summarize`

```
NHANES %>%
 filter(Gender == "female") %>%
 group_by(AgeDecade) %>%
 summarize(average = mean(BPSysAve, na.rm = TRUE),
           standard_diviation = sd(BPSysAve, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
 na.omit()
```

Don't understand what is wrong with my code. Data camp doesn't accept it.

Comment: what is wrong? Does it throw error?

Comment: is it the typo in `standard_deviation`? and the `na.omit()` is imo not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
 NHANES %>%
  filter(Gender == "female") %>%
  group_by(AgeDecade) %>%
  summarize(average = mean(BPSysAve, na.rm = TRUE),
       standard_diviation = sd(BPSysAve, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
   .[complete.cases(.),]
```

The issue is that you have only 3 variables in the final output. The last line in the code can be replaced with "filter(!is.na(AgeDecade))" since you are unlikely to have NA otherwise.